# How to create endpoint that returns responseentity by calling external endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an endpoint in one application and I would like to create endpoint in another app which will call the first one.

First one is

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PASSWORD_RESET)
public class ResetPasswordController {
    private final ResetPasswordService passwordService;
    private final AgentUtils agentUtils;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @PostMapping(SEND_CODE)
    @HasPermission(Permission.PUBLIC)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Sending password reset code",
            notes = "Validate request. Generates a random 6 digit value and send it as an SMS to the agent.",
            code = 200, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendPasswordResetCode(@RequestHeader(HEADER_TENANT_ID) Long tenantId,
            @Valid @RequestBody SendResetPasswordCodeReqDto sendResetPasswordCodeReqDto) {

        if (!passwordService.isAgentExist(tenantId, sendResetPasswordCodeReqDto.getSocialId(),
                sendResetPasswordCodeReqDto.getPhone())) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        passwordService.sendPasswordResetCode(tenantId, sendResetPasswordCodeReqDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

The service I am attempting to create

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ResetPasswordService{
    private static final String RESET_PASSWORD_URL = "/password-reset";

    public ResetPasswordService(SettingsService settingsService,
            RestTemplate restTemplate,
            MicroServicesHeadersService loginHeadersService) {
        super(settingsService, restTemplate, loginHeadersService);
    }

    public String sendPasswordResetCode(Long tenantId, SendResetPasswordCodeReqDto sendResetPasswordCodeReqDto) {
       try {
           String responseFromExtService = postToExtServices(
                   sendResetPasswordCodeReqDto, SEND_CODE_URL, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}
           ).getBody();
           return responseFromExtService;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           log.error("Failed to get password reset code");
           throw e;
       }
    }

@SneakyThrows
    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postToExtServices(Object dto, String url, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType) {
        String jsonBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonBody, httpHeadersService.getDefaultHttpHeaders());

        return restTemplate.exchange(
                getResourceUrl() + url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                request,
                responseType
        );
    }
```

The issue is that the return type of sendPasswordResetCode() is a String in my current implementation and I wish to change it to `ResponseEntity<String>` like in the first endpoint. Not sure if I have to change my `postToExtServices()` or should I change the `sendPasswordResetCode()`?

Comment: I think your question is a bit unclear. Your second piece of code, `PasswordResetService`, is located in application A, right? And it will consume the API from the first piece of code, the `ResetPasswordController` that is hosted in application B?

Comment: @Titulum Sorry about that. The second piece of code ```PasswordResetService``` is located in application B. I have a controller there which will do a Post and it will call this service which will make the call to application A.

Comment: I see. I think it's bad practice for the `PasswordResetService` to return a `ResponseEntity`. Make it return an object that conveys the result of the operation, and let the `Controller` wrap it in a `ResponseEntity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood your question at first.

What you mean is:

`ResetPasswordController` is hosted in application A.
`ResetPasswordService` is hosted in application B, but will call upon application A in the `postToExtServices` method?

If that is the case, I would advice that the `sendPasswordResetCode` would not return a `ResponeEntity`. `ResponseEntities` are typically used by the `Controller` layer of your application.

Try to isolate each object in the layer that it belongs to, something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The approach you followed in correct, In the controller just capture the output from service layer

```
String body = passwordService.sendPasswordResetCode(tenantId, sendResetPasswordCodeReqDto);
```

And then in the `Controller` just add the body and status code to `ResponseEntity`

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(body);
```